# Why Int32.TryParse returns false for number?

Tags: c#, parsing, int, tryparse

I have this code:

```
string sPhone = "420777777777";
int rPhone;
bool valid = Int32.TryParse(sPhone, out rPhone); //false
if (!valid)
 return "";
return String.Format("{0:+### ### ### ###}", rPhone);
```

I want to format phone number so I'm converting string to int, but value of `valid` is always false. How can I convert this string to int? I was also trying `int.TryParse` or `Convert.ToInt32`. Nothing worked.

Comment: If you can't add them together they're not numbers. What's Sarah's phone number plus Blair's?

Comment: Why would you convert a phone number to an integer in the first place?  Are you intending to do calculations with it?

Comment: I need to show it formatted (last row), for that I need it converted to int.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because [Int32.MaxValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) is **2147483647** so, the conversion of your string "420777777777" will never be a valid value for an Int32 ;

Use

```
string sPhone = "420777777777";
long rPhone;
bool valid = Int64.TryParse(sPhone, out rPhone); 
return (!valid ? "" : string.Format("{0:+### ### ### ###}", rPhone));
```

Answer (score 0):

Int32 is a 32 bit digit, max value for it is 2147483647 or 4294967295 for UInt32. you can try using long.TryParse if you have a 64 bit architecture.

Comment: on 32 bit architecture long will have same max value as Int32. That means that it won't help to solve this problem.

Comment: Int64(or long).MaxValue is constant and defined as 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, no matter what architecture you use.